# get data from sharepoint list that expires in 10 or less days

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list and I would like to get the data that is about to expire in 10 or less days. So I have two fields creation date and expire date.

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this using spquery or anyother way in sharepoint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to query data (Excluding querying across an entire site collection) SPQuery and SPMetal(LINQ to SharePoint).

In general I try to use SPMetal generated objects and only go to CAML(SPQuery) for complex queries.

Here is 2 examples first using SPMetal objects.

```
ExporttestsDataContext context = new ExporttestsDataContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);

        var data = from d in context.Demo
                   where d.Expire < DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) && d.Expire >= DateTime.Now
                   select d;

        foreach (DemoItem item in data)
        {                
            //dowork
        }
```

Now SPQuery

```
            SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Demo"];
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "<Where><And><Lt><FieldRef Name='Expire' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='10' /></Value></Lt><Geq><FieldRef Name='Expire' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Geq></And></Where>";

        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
            //DoWork
        }
```

For some information on CAML see http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list.   (I had to use OffsetDays instead of Offset to get the above working).

Can just google SPMetal for more information on it.  One tool that is nice is the CKS Development tools as it can generate this class(es) with just a few clicks in visual studio.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks a lot for your quick reply. I just logged in on my computer. I will give your code a try and let you know about my progress. Thanks again and you are great!!

Comment: Hi Josh, I tried you code, but I cannot get it to display only those items that are to expire in 10 or less days. I tried changing the code but to not avail. 

What I want is something that give me this kind of result, eg: 
if(expire <= 10)
{
get the data
}

Comment: Hi Josh, the problem is solved. Your code was correct. I was making a mistake with the field names.